# splitting a string based on some rules

Tags: java, regex

I have a number in format

```
10.10.09.09.00
```

Now i want to find the first three places:

```
String getformattedString(Strring str){
  //impl
  return newStr;
}
```

eg `10.10.09.`
How can i do it?

Answer (score 4):

Don't have to use a regex, this would work too:

```
String[] fields = str.split("\\.");

return fields[0] + "." + fields[1] + "." + fields[2] + ".";
```

Comment: But it doesn't check whether it's only numbers between the dots (why I assume is implied here ("I have number in format..."))

Comment: but this code IS using regex - the argument to `split` is one! The javadoc of split says "Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression. "

Comment: @Carlos: yes you are of course correct. However it's a very simple one :)

Answer (score 4):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^(?:\\d+\\.){3}");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
   // matched text: regexMatcher.group()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-line solution:

```
public static String getFormattedString(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("(^(\\d\\d\\.){3}).*", "$1");
}
```

Here's the test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getFormattedString("10.10.09.09.00"));
}
```

Output:

```
10.10.09.
```

Answer (score 0):

[Regular expressions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) sounds like what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this too:

```
return str.Substring(0, str.LastIndexOf(".", str.LastIndexOf(".") - 1) + 1)
```